# Remove QGraphicsPixMapItem (by setParentItem)

Tags: c++, qt

So I'm having trouble with removing a QGraphicsPixMapItem. I add it to my view by setting it's parent so I expected that if I would change the parent to nullptr it would be removed but it didn't work. I read online that I could also use functions like hide but when I use these the program crashes. Whats the best way to fix this?

Btw I'm sure the code crashes when I call the hide function and the rest of my code is good.

A left click should add a 'stamlid' (QGraphicsPixMapItem) to the QGraphicsEllipsItem (this). And It should be removed with a right click.

```
void Vakje::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event) {
    Speler *speler = m_spel->getAanDeBeurt();
    if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton && m_stamlid == nullptr) {
        m_stamlid = speler->getVrijeStamleden()[0]; //stamlid van speler dat niet op bord staat
        m_stamlid->getStamlidView()->setParentItem(this);
        m_stamlid->setOpBord(true);
        m_stamlid->getStamlidView()->setVisible(true);
        speler->getSpelerView()->updateMembers();

    } else if (event->button() == Qt::RightButton && m_stamlid != nullptr) { //verwijder pion
        m_stamlid->setOpBord(false);
        m_stamlid->getStamlidView()->setParentItem(nullptr);
        m_stamlid = nullptr;
        speler->getSpelerView()->updateMembers();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Qt documentation for the base class [QGraphicsItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#setParentItem) explains that setting the parent item to 0 does not remove the item, but makes it a top-level item instead.

Perhaps what you should do is get the item's [scene](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#scene) and use it to [remove](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#removeItem) the item.

```
if (m_stamlid->scene())
    m_stamlid->scene()->removeItem(m_stamlid);
delete m_stamlid;
m_stamlid = nullptr;
```